# Error when publishing Tableau Public Workbook

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to publish a Workbook in Tableau Public. I am very new at Tableau and have this problem 50% of the times I've attempted to publish. I get an error message that says "Couldn't save workbook: To access this workbook, you must have the Connect permission for its data source."

I have already extracted the data as suggested by other sources. All of the information I've found online about this error is old (6mo+) and the platform has changed since then and is not applicable. I am very new and don't understand a lot of technical jargon so please explain it LIFT.

Error:
[I had a screenshot of the error but I'm not allowed to embed images yet. idk.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXFHs.png)

Comment: Thanks for the post edit suggestion, Ethan. I don't know how to tag you.

Comment: Are you saving the workbook as a .twbx file before you try to publish?

Comment: No, I can't save on Tableau. I can only Publish. They got rid of the save function and a window pops up that says "Where's Save? Save your stuff by Publishing" or something similar.